# Picasso library not loading images with color space YCCB

Tags: android, image, rgb, picasso, cmyk

I try to load various images from URLs into ImageViews. Some are being loaded by Picasso, some are not. I think I managed to find the difference in these images. They vary in the "Color Space".

Following image has a color space value of YUV and gets loaded by Picasso:
http://m.fpoe.at/typo3temp/pics/967b6df704.jpg

This image has a color space value of YCCB and does not get loaded by Picasso:
http://m.fpoe.at/uploads/pics/2014_oktoberfest_494.jpg

Is this due to the fact that Android does not load CMYK images? Is the YCCB a CMYK image?

Thanks

## EDIT 1:

I change my initial question, because it was not describing a correct behaviour. I thought the images differ only in chroma subsampling. But this was not the problem. The problem is the color space YUV and YCCB.

## EDIT 2:

This is the Exception I get when I try to load a image with YCCB color space in Android Studio:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Incompatible color conversion   at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.checkColorConversion(JPEGImageReader.java:973)   at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(JPEGImageReader.java:1078)   at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(JPEGImageReader.java:1034)   at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1448)   at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1308)   at android.graphics.Bitmap_Delegate.createBitmap(Bitmap_Delegate.java:118)   at android.graphics.Bitmap_Delegate.createBitmap(Bitmap_Delegate.java:102)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:236)   at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getDrawable(BridgeTypedArray.java:789)   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:136)   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:125)   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:121)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:603)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:678)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:737)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:778)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:500)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:381)
```

Comment: "Can you reproduce the behaviour I get with the above provides URLs?" That's really not what we're here for. Why don't you skip Picasso and see if Android's ImageViews can display those images in the raw?

Comment: I changed the question. Not asking if anyone can reproduce it.

Also I find it hard to do everything Picasso does (downloading, caching) by myself. This would mean a great effort on caching, downloading images as well as coding.

Comment: Download the image manually, put it in your resources, try to display it.

Comment: I downloaded an image with a "Color Space" "YCCB" and the "Chroma Subsampling" of "4:4:4:4". It does not load in the Android App. Also the Android Studio does not load the image when I go into Preview mode. I added the Exception I get in Android Studio to my Post.

Comment: I think the problem is that the color space of the error image is CMYK. And as far as I know Android does not support CMYK images. Is there a way to handle CMYK images loaded from an URL with Picasso?

Comment: You'll need to convert it, plain and simple. It has nothing to do with picasso, but with the image format.